# Allow user to "scroll past" ViewPager in a LinearLayout.

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a linear layout with two elements in it a ViewPager and a RecyclerView. Currently when the user scrolls down the ViewPager stays at the top of the page. Preferably the what would happen is that the user would scroll past the ViewPager so that the RecyclerView took up the page. How can I make this happen?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListEventsActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pager"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/user_recycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make `ViewPage` to be header of `RecyclerView`

Comment: When I make the RecyclerView a child of the ViewPager it doesn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, you need to set the height to 0dp while applying

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListEventsActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pager"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:id="@+id/user_recycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to be working. It results in the RecyclerView getting pushed down the page and scrolling still doesn't work as I'd like.

Comment: @Steve do you want to equal height to both based on the screen size?

Comment: ideally the ViewPager would be a bit smaller than the RecyclerView.

Comment: unfortunately it's still not working. When I scroll down the ViewPager stays at the top.